# Regular expression for b%x

Tags: php, regex

How can I make regular expression for **b%***x* with *x>0* and *x<20*
so that my program accepts these:

```
b%1
b%2
b%3
b%4
...
b%19


function regex(value)
{
    $regex = '???';
    if (preg_match(regex, value)) {
        echo "A match was found.";
    } else {
        echo "A match was not found.";
    }
}
```

How can I make it?

```
function regex(value)
{
    $regex = '???';
    if (preg_match(regex, value)) {
        echo "A match was found.";
    } else {
        echo "A match was not found.";
    }
}
```

Comment: What regexes have you tried so far?

Comment: You really don't need regex for this, just explode by `%`, check if the size is 2, check if the first index is `b` and the second is between 1 and 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the regex you searching for looks like this:

```
$regex = "^b%([1-9]|[1]\d|20)$";
```

`^` and `$` is to set the start and the end for your string

`b%` if your prefix

`[1-9]` number from 1 to 9
OR

`[1]\d` number from 10 to 19
OR

`20` number 20

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are supposed to be on a line all by themselves and you're literal about the number (no 0 pre-pad, etc):

```
 /^b%([1-9]|(1[0-9]))\s*$/
```

Comment: "on a line all by themselves" makes it sound like you want the `m`ultiline modifier, and the pattern allows up to `29`.

Comment: I really meant if a check for end of line was needed at the end of the regex, i.e., not allow any other extraneous information after the desired information. And, oops, good catch! :)

Comment: In that case, you probably want to use the `D` modifier. Unless trailing newlines are to be allowed.